# Get commit metadata from remote repository without fetching commit content

Tags: git, github, github-api

I would like to get commit metadata like that returned by the `git cat-file -p <COMMIT-ID>` (see this example from Git itself)

```
 $ git cat-file -p a4ee444

 tree 34f4cce68fd066d044dcbca866a161fa5c98dc6b
 parent 1f9c1fab6421402a9c893a2fcd35fb4cf6116166
 parent ffa952497288d29d94b16675c6789ef83850def3
 author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1518737095 -0800
 committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1518737095 -0800
 mergetag object ffa952497288d29d94b16675c6789ef83850def3
  type commit
  tag v2.16.2
  tagger Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1518737031 -0800

  Git 2.16.2
  -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
            ...
  -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

 Sync with 2.16.2

 * tag 'v2.16.2':
   Git 2.16.2
```

but without having to fetch the entire commit with all its files.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get this remote information via the `git` client program, or by some other means, like using Git's internal transfer protocols?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [get information about a commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit) using GitHub API.

For example using `curl` in command line:

```
curl -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/phdru/ppu/git/commits/63c535d7c6b151c210e344dd4b745407f3911d76
```

(this is [a commit](https://github.com/phdru/ppu/commit/63c535d7c6b151c210e344dd4b745407f3911d76) from my repository)

For authentication pass `-u`:

```
curl -u user:password …
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it is very useful too, but I am looking for a solution independent from a public repository provider, a solution that can work with any provider or without a provider, only with Git client and server. Thanks

Comment: What you want is not possible with pure git. You've used [github] and [github-api] tags so I answered with GitHub API. Remove the tags if you're not interested in GitHub and I remove my answer.

Comment: My fault to cause any misunderstanding with the use of those tags. But I would like you to keep your answer because it can be useful to other people landing here. I inclusively upvoted it.

Comment: Well, I am going to accept this answer, as for now, this is the lowest effort means that gets close to the solution I was looking for.

Comment: github commit api is lossy, the timezones are missing for commit time and author time. see [my workaround](https://github.com/milahu/python-fuse-githubfs/blob/bf782670d136ff8a763b147ba615ff55f5f63b8a/githubfs/verify_github_api.py#L118) to guess the timezones

Answer (score 2):

> is [it] possible to get this remote information via the git client program,

No: even with shallow clones, the clients "want" all the objects that are needed to complete a commit.

> or by some other means, like using Git's internal transfer protocols?

Possibly, as long as there is a name pointing to it, or the server is running on a repository that has `uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant` configured to `true`, or has `uploadpack.allowAnySHA1InWant` configured to `true`.  Senders don't normally negotiate about tree objects, though: they just assume that you have objects reachable from commits that you (as a receiver) say that you have.  So it's not designed to work this way.

Note that the PGP signature in a `mergetag object ...` header inside a commit is simply copied from the annotated tag.  I have not tried it, but a shallow clone with depth *zero* might work to retrieve all tags (only).  In this case, you could just look at the tag object.  This part *is* designed to work this way, and seems more promising.  Moreover, annotated tag objects normally have tag *names* pointing to them, so you don't need the special `uploadpack` configuration entries: these objects are directly published and hence always "want"-able.

(Of course you would have to find the right tag name, and it's not clear how you would do that without the commit data.  On the other hand, it's not clear how you would find the commit hash in the first place.)

The actual tag object in this case is:

```
$ git rev-parse v2.16.2
86aabcca24951ccfb9392014c8a379992434a7df
$ git cat-file -p v2.16.2
object ffa952497288d29d94b16675c6789ef83850def3
type commit
tag v2.16.2
tagger Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1518737031 -0800

Git 2.16.2
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=rp/y
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems you know something interesting about this topic, but your answer is not clear to me. Since it is not always possible to control the `uploadpack` configuration, can you provide a clear example on how to get a commit's metadata only given a "name pointing to it"? Thanks

Comment: @mljrg: I don't know that you *can* do that; that's the point of the "not designed to work this way" part of the answer. You would have to extract the Git client code that connects to the server, modify it to say that it wants the given commit (find the have/want code in the source), and make sure that if it is asked about additional hash IDs, it says it has all of them. I think you'd still wind up receiving a pack that has some tree and blob objects, though.

Comment: To see more of what I'm talking about without diving into any code, run `git ls-remote origin` and observe what comes out. Note that if you want to use the GitHub API, this is very different from the internal Git protocols you mentioned in your question.

Comment: ok ... that's what I had suspected: that I would need to dive into the code, the packets, and the like. Thanks.